# Specific block not rendering inside of a static block

Tags: blocks, static-block, cms-pages, ee-1.14.2.4

Works fine in a **CMS** page.

But I need to render this block in a **static block**:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="37"  template="tm/quickbuy/catalog/product/list.phtml”}}
```

The block above is very similar except with different directory paths to the one below. When i insert the one below it works. The one above does not work.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="4"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml”}}
```

- I've made sure they are whitelisted.
- I've tried to change directories by putting the top block in the same directory as the bottom block.

Any idea to why my first block does not render properly?

Answer (score 2):

1) First of all, are you sure that the first phtml exsiste? If this is the case, try displaying just a simple string something like `<?php die('test'); ?>` and remove `category_id="37"`paramater from `{{...}}`then look if you render this string "test" ? If this is not the case it is that you have a problem either in block type or the path to phtml.

2) Verify that category `37` exsist.

3) Check if you have mentioned the correct path to the custom `.phtml` and the correct `type of block`.

4) Clean your cache.